# google finance syntax error when printing

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

from pandas_datareader import data, wb


goog = web.DataReader('GOOG', data_source='google', start='3/14/2017',end='9/14/2017')

print goog.head()
```

Why does it shows invalid syntax for `goog`?

Thank you

Comment: If you are on python 3, `print()` is a function.  You need to use `print(goog.head())`.  What you have is python 2 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out because in Python 3 they replace it with a function so the correct type is:

print (goog.head())